# loading redux items into state from a direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is sort of a "best practices" question, since I'm not clear on the right way to handle this case.

The situation is that I have a bookstore app with a list of `books` that exists as `state.bookstore.books`. When the visitor loads the index page of the bookstore, a `thunk` action is dispatched that loads all the `book` objects in the user's collection into the `state.bookstore.books` array.

From the bookstore page, a user can click on an individual book, and a new page is loaded that pulls the `book` item from the state `books` array and displays the details.

My problem is that if a user directly visits the book detail link (eg. "mysite.com/book/123") without first going through the homepage, the `state.bookstore.books` array is empty, and the page has no data to display.

My question is what is the "right" way to do this? Would I dispatch the `loadBookstore` action to populate the state anytime the app is initialized? Would I create a new redux feature for `book`? Would I ignore looking up the `book` in the state, and just grab the specific `book` record from the server?

I am assuming that I'm doing it wrong / implementing an anti-pattern because selectors are not built to take parameters, so it seems like since there's no easy way to grab book `123` from the store, then I shouldn't be doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have 2 components

1. `BooksHome` for `/books/`
2. `SingleBook` for `/books/:id`

So when the user visits `/books/` route, fire a thunk `fetchBooks(..)` which loads books and saves them in `state.bookstore.books` and display those books in `BooksHome`

And when the user visits `/books/:id` route, fire a thunk `fetchSingleBook(..)` which will find book item with `:id` in `state.bookstore.books` if that's present return it and display it in `SingleBook` and if it's not there, fetch it, add it to `state.bookstore.books` and return it and display it in
`SingleBook`.

Explanation:

When the user visits `/books/123` right away, `state.bookstore.books` is `[]` so no item is found, so we'll fetch it, store it and display it.

When the user visits `/books/` (data fetched and stored) and then visits `/books/123`, `state.bookstore.books` is having an item with `id:123` so the item is found, so we'll get it from `state.bookstore.books` and display it.

Must do things:

1. `fetchBooks` must be dispatched in `BooksHome` but not in `App`
2. Same way `fetchSingleBook` must be dispatched in `SingleBook`

Things optimised with this approach:

1. We need not fetch all books for displaying a single book.
2. We need not re-fetch book's data when it is already available in `state.bookstore.books`

Hope this helps