# How to manage redux state when user hits a product details page directly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux

I am working on a Redux app and I have come across a particular situation that I don't know how to handle.

Let's say I have a `ProductsList` page: `example.com/products`

On this page, I am dispatching the `getProducts` redux action and it calls the API and stores the products in the store.

And on this page, I list all the products. Now, the user clicks on a product and a new URL is pushed like: `example.com/products/product/1`

And on this `ProductDetails` page, a redux action called `setCurrentProduct` gets dispatched.

So far, it is good.

But the problem happens, when the user visits the URL `example.com/products/product/1` directly.

In that case, the `setCurrentProduct` action gets dispatched but it fails because there are no products in the store yet.

I think I can add an if-else statement to this `ProductDetails` page and check if the products are not present in the store, then first dispatch the `getProducts` and then `setCurrentProduct`.

But I feel this is a hacky solution.

Maybe, I am wrong and this is the actual solution.

Can someone please guide me on whether this solution is correct, if not, then what is the correct solution.

PS: I am using NextJS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the back-end service should provide two APIs:

- `/api/products` - Return product list DTOs, the DTO should contain basic info of a product.
- `/api/product/:id` - Return the product detail DTO, the DTO should contain full detail of a product.

For the front-end, the `example.com/products` route should call the `/api/products` API.

The `examlpe.com/product/:id` should call the `/api/product/:id` API.

You don't need any conditional statements. The details page does not depend on the Redux state of the list page.

The state structure in redux store can be(non-normalized, just for demo):

```js
state = {
  products: { status: 'idle', data: [], error: null },
  productDetail: { status: 'idle', data: {}, error: null }
};
```

The product list component uses the `state.products`, the product detail component uses the `state.productDetail`.

When a user accesses the product detail directly, the component should launch a new API call to get the product detail.

It's not related to NextJs or any other framework.

Comment: Hi @slideshownp2, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. 

Your solution totally makes sense and I agree with you.

But there are probably more than one ways to handle this problem.

Comment: If we think of user journey like he visits the ```example.com/products``` page first and then goes to ```example.com/products/product/1``` page, maybe loading ```products``` on the first page and then setting the current product by getting data from ```products``` array can save us one extra API call.

but that way, we can't handle the scenario I posted in the question.

Maybe, using a conditional statement, we can do that.

Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943891/loading-redux-items-into-state-from-a-direct-link